# createForm throws an error Expected argument of type "string" (migrate from 2.7 to 3.0)

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm getting an exception

`Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\BasicForm" given

500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException`

while accessing the url. Please see the code as below which was working with symfony 2.7 and facing this issue after migrating to 3.0.

The controller code is,

`

```
    /**
     * @Route("/basicForm", name="displayBasicForm")
     * @param $request - The request parameter
     * @return the Response
     */
 public function displayForm(Request $request) {
        $model = new FormModel();
        $dropDownDatas = array();
        $dropDownDatas["cityLists"] = $this->get("city_dao")->fetchAllCities('USA');
        $dropDownDatas["areaLists"] = $this->get("area_dao")->fetchAllAreas(1);

        $formObj = new BasicForm($dropDownDatas);
        $areaForm = $this->createForm($formObj, $model);
}
```

`The formtype is,`

```
class BasicForm extends AbstractType {

    protected $dropDownDatas;

    public function __construct($dropDownDatas)
    {
        $this->dropDownDatas = $dropDownDatas;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)       {
        $cityLists = $this->dropDownDatas['cityLists'];
        $areaLists = $this->dropDownDatas['areaLists'];

        $builder->add('cityId', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $cityLists,
            'empty_data'  => null))
            ->add('areaId', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $areaLists,
                'empty_data'  => null));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'basicForm';
    }
}
```

`

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in `createForm` method the fully qualified class name of the form type see [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L283)

So you should to do somethink like this :

```
$form = $this->createForm(BasicForm::class, $model);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. If you look at my form construct method it expects an array whose holding the required values. How do I pass that argument $dropDownDatas from the controller to the form construct?

Comment: You can set it in the options argument $form = $this->createForm(BasicForm::class, $model, array('dropDownDatas' => $dropDownDatas)); then you can get those values in the buildForm method public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

Comment: I tried that in the meantime, now it throws another error, "The option "dropDownDatas" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields""

Comment: Move to 2.8 before going to 3.0.  Then get rid of all the depreciation notices in 2.8.  That will allow easing the form transition.  Might also take a look at defining form types as services to help with the injection problem: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: As @Cerad said you need to register your form type as a service if you need to pass data to its constructor. However, data that is specific to the actual form (like with your dropdown data) should not be passed to the form type's constructor, but should be configured through a custom option when the actual form is created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "elkorchi anas" for the quick reply and that helped me to fix it.

In the controller, pass the additional values in the $options array like

  `array('dropDownDatas' => $dropDownDatas)`

In the FormType override function

    `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('dropDownDatas' => null));
    }`

In the build form read it like,

    `$options['dropDownDatas']['cityLists'];`